# MySQL SELECTs how to join

Tags: mysql, select

I have these tables on a MySQL Database:

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurante(
    nombreRest VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    telefono INT(9) NOT NULL, 
    domicilio VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    nTenedores ENUM('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL,
    tipoCocina VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    nombreCiudad VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    idRestaurante SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idRestaurante),
    FOREIGN KEY (tipoCocina) REFERENCES tipoCocina(tipoCocina),
    FOREIGN KEY (nombreCiudad) REFERENCES Ciudad(nombreCiudad)
)

CREATE TABLE Servicio(
    idServicio SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    precioT DOUBLE(2,2) NOT NULL, 
    franjaServicio VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    cafe BOOLEAN,
    beINbida BOOLEAN,
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    idRestaurante SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idServicio),
    FOREIGN KEY (idRestaurante) REFERENCES Restaurante(idRestaurante)
)

CREATE TABLE Plato(
    nombrePlato VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    descripción VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    idRestaurante SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (nombrePlato),
    FOREIGN KEY (idRestaurante) REFERENCES Restaurante(idRestaurante)
)

CREATE TABLE Menu(
    idServicio SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    PrimerPlato VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SegundoPlato VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Postre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idServicio) REFERENCES Servicio(idServicio),
    FOREIGN KEY (PrimerPlato) REFERENCES Plato(nombrePlato),
    FOREIGN KEY (SegundoPlato) REFERENCES Plato(nombrePlato),
    FOREIGN KEY (Postre) REFERENCES Plato(nombrePlato),
    PRIMARY KEY (idServicio)

)
```

(don't know if they're good, just taking my first course on DB, any suggestions would be appreciated)

I need to show the list of nombreRest, telefono, domicilio of a Restaurant where they have a menu with these three plato ('Arros Brut', 'Porcella', 'Pijama').

I've made three diferent selects and my idea is to find a way to join them somehow but i dont know how that would work.

```
SELECT idServicio
FROM Menu
WHERE PrimerPlato = 'Arros Brut' AND SegundoPlato = 'Porcella' AND Postre = 'Pijama'

SELECT idRestaurante 
FROM Servicio
WHERE Servicio.idRestaurante = idServicio

SELECT (nombreRest, telefono, domicilio)
FROM Restaurante
WHERE Restaurante.idRestaurante = idRestaurante
```

Comment: Great work posting the DDL, thank you for that! Now complete it by [edit]ing the question and providing sample data as `INSERT` statements and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the attributes marked as a foreign key to make a join on another table. This foreign key corresponds to the primary key of the other table.

For example:

```
SELECT r.nombreRest, r.telefono, r.domicilio
FROM Restaurante r 
JOIN Servicio s
    ON r.idRestaurante = s.idRestaurante
JOIN Menu m
    ON m.idServicio = s.idServicio
WHERE m.PrimerPlato = 'Arros Brut'
    AND m.SegundoPlato = 'Porcella'
    AND m.Postre = 'Pijama';
```

If I'm correct you should also join the Plato table to the query. I don't see you do it in your example so hopefully this works.

This [website](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) explains some more about the different joins you can make

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, what do you mean with adding Plato, and how would that work?

Comment: If I understand your tables correct the Plato table contains the unique dish.

Normally you put a primary key on a digit type like number or (small)int instead of a (var)char.

If you want to adjust it you change it like below.

I would then add an 'idPlato' SMALLINT to the Plato table and make that the primary key, and add the UNIQUE constraint to the nombrePlato.
Then change Menu.PrimerPlato, Menu.SegundoPlato and Menu.Postre to SMALLINT instead of the VARCHAR.

Comment: Your select statement would then look like this:

SELECT r.nombreRest, r.telefono, r.domicilio
FROM Restaurante r 
JOIN Servicio s
    ON r.idRestaurante = s.idRestaurante
JOIN Menu m
    ON m.idServicio = s.idServicio
WHERE m.PrimerPlato = (SELECT idPlato FROM Plato WHERE nombrePlato = 'Arros Brut')
    AND m.SegundoPlato = (SELECT idPlato FROM Plato WHERE nombrePlato = 'Porcella')
    AND m.Postre = (SELECT idPlato FROM Plato WHERE nombrePlato = Pijama');